# Main site suspensions to refresh chat profiles

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, moderator-tools, account-suspension

Currently, for actively chatting users, if a moderator suspends on main, they have to manually refresh the chat profile of the offending user. Until they do, said user still has chat privileges.

Could a suspension automatically cause the chat profile associated with the user to refresh from parent?

Comment: You don't *have* to manually refresh the profile - it will carry over eventually (an hour, I think, at maximum?). But yeah, instant would be better.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this would require a script triggered on a suspension, because it's cross-site?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I've just had a case on Stack Overflow where it didn't update after several hours

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Was that on chat.SO or chat.SE? Might conceivably be different systems for the two.

Comment: @randal'thor chat.SO.